# VBA msgbox error

Tags: vba, msgbox

my error is
Compile error:
expected =

msgbox (" Final Score:" & "P1score " & P1 & "P2score " & P2 & "P3score " & P3 & "P4score " & P4,vbOKOnly,"GameOver")

I was wondering how to fix this

Comment: you could just remove the brackets. `MsgBox Join(Array("Final Score:", "P1score " & P1, "P2score " & P2, "P3score " & P3, "P4score " & P4), vbCrLf), vbOKOnly, "GameOver"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsgBox is a function which return a value ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).

If you don't care about the return value then:

```
Call MsgBox(.....)
```

If you do care then:

```
returnValue = MsgBox(.....)
```

You may need to define 'returnValue' first.